# check if input matches current shown item in array with php

Tags: php, arrays, search, input

I have a texfield `$input` and an array with strings `$word`. I am shuffling the array and showing the shuffled string from the `$words` array which the user has to match.

If the shuffled (the shuffled string is also the current shown string) string is `hello` the user has to type `hello` and then a message says "correct!" or `wrong!` (if it does not match 100%).

So, how do I simply check if the users input is equal to the current shown string in the `$words` array? I have searched a lot for this but could not find anything.

When the user types the corresponding word a new "random" word from the array is shown and must be typed correctly as shown. The program keeps going like this.

I have tried this:

```
<form method = "post" action = "<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
            <input type = "text" name = "inputfield" id = "inputfield"><br>
            <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "TJEK SPELLING" id = "spelling"><br>
        </form>

$word = array("hello", "how", "are", "you", "great", "fine");
shuffle($word);

//The word that has to be matched is shown
echo reset($word);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $input = $_POST['inputfield'];
            echo "You typed : <b> $input </b>";
            echo "<br>That was : ";

            if (in_array($input, $word)) {
                echo "<b>Correct!</b>";
            } else{
                echo "<b>Wrong</b>";
            }
        }
```

With this code I check whether it is inside the array or not, I know, but this is my closest bet.

Here is a screenshot from my mini-program:

[image]

Any help appreciated.
Thanks, in advance!

Comment: and your current code isn't working?

Comment: show your form code also. and basically what you want? you want that user given input matches in array, if yes then matched otherwise not? is it right?

Comment: please check updates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are after, I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['inputField']) && isset($_POST['shownWord'])) 
{
    $input = $_POST['inputField'];
    echo "You typed : <b> $input </b>";
    echo "<br>That was : ";

    if ($input === $_POST['shownWord']) {
        echo "<b>Correct!</b>";
    } else{
        echo "<b>Wrong</b>";
    }
}

$word = array("hello", "how", "are", "you", "great", "fine");
shuffle($word);
$toMatch = reset($word);
?>
<p>Enter this word: <?php echo $toMatch; ?></p>
<form name ="form" method = "POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="shownWord" value="<?php echo $toMatch; ?>" />
    <input type="text" name = "inputField" >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Depending on your needs, it would probably be better to save the random word to a [session](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) and then check the matched word from there. E.g:

```
$_SESSION['shownWord'] = $toMatch;
```

And change the if statement to:

```
if ($input === $_SESSION['shownWord']) { }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as assigning the word you need to match to a variable and then comparing:

```
<?php

$word = array("hello", "how", "are", "you", "great", "fine");
shuffle($word);

//The word that has to be matched is shown
$toMatch = reset($word);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $input = $_POST['inputfield'];
    echo "You typed : <b> $input </b>";
    echo "<br>That was : ";

    if ($input === $toMatch) {
        echo "<b>Correct!</b>";
    } else{
        echo "<b>Wrong</b>";
    }
}
```

Comment: This code only works for the first show string. But the program should keep working. I mean, a new word should appear and the user has to match it.

Comment: Can you please post the view how does it looks and what you need to show @me72921

Comment: @me72921 You have to add javascript and ajax to make something "live" – this is all backend, it is processed once and that's it..

Comment: @Crembo, I will surely work on your advice to do this in Javascript and Ajax.